# How to set the pycharm debugger to list the method functions of an object in the variable watch?

Tags: python, pycharm, pdb

Is there anyway to view the method functions of an object in the pycharm debugger?

The image shows a bunch of properties, which is useful, but it does not show any methods inside the object. Is there a way to see them?

If I type dir(object) in pdb, everything is listed. How do I turn on the visual equivalent in pycharm?

[image]

Comment: you can vote this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27760

Comment: Vote on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14849 .  PY-27760 is locked because it duplicates PY-14849.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `debug Console` while you are stopped at a breakpoint. You can inspect things, modify, etc. Can be dangerous, but useful.

Some people have complained recently about the debugger console not working properly, but I haven't experienced that. I'm on the latest EAP (2017.2.?)

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
    def bar(self):
        self.a = 4
    def that(self):
        return self.a
b = foo()
print("My breakpoint is here.")
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's nice, I guess there's no visual equivalent though for the variable watch window?